# Deleting space on my iphone/icloud

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos, storage, dropbox

If I am storing photos on my Dropbox or Google Photos, can I delete them from my iCloud and still access them through these other apps?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, those services are not connected.

However, once you delete items from iCloud, they'll be deleted from every device you have that uses that same Apple ID.  iCloud is a sync services whereas Dropbox and Google Drive are cloud storage that can also be used for backup.

Comment: Just wanted to note that iCloud is also a cloud storage platform - especially with iCloud Drive

Comment: Yes, sort of.  I didn't want to muddy the water with that because the 1) OP appears to be a new/inexperienced Apple user and 2) he didn't ask about Drive and I didn't want to cause confusion by adding that part.